# what's meaning of "have you brought over to my place in the morning."

Tags: grammar

There's a sentence of dialogue from Walking Dead that confused me:

> have you brought over to my place in the morning.

This is not a interrogative sentence. Why does it put the "have" in the first place of this sentence? What's the grammar here?

Comment: Is that the entire phrase that was spoken? It looks incomplete to me, I would expect it to start with something like "I will".

Comment: Or "I'm going to".

Comment: For those Walking Dead fans who are wondering about the context, I think I've discovered it. The governor is welcoming Michone and Andrea to Woodbury: "...now you're not prisoners here, you're guests, if you want to leave, as I said, you're free to do so, we don't open the gates past dusk, draws too much attention; and you especially, you need a solid night's sleep, you wouldn't last another day out there in your condition; have you brought over to my place in the morning, return your weapons, extra ammo, food for the road, some meds, keys to a vehicle if you want."

Comment: @JoJo: I don't remember the episode, but as others have commented, the sentence is missing something (the subject and part of the verb). The Governor probably said "we'll" but it was lost in his thick southern accent. In any case, he certainly *meant* "we will" to go before "have."

Answer (score 1):

It's definition 2.5 from [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have)

> [WITH PAST PARTICIPLE] Cause (something) to be done for one by someone else:
>   it is advisable to have your carpet laid by a professional

The speaker is going to get someone else to bring the person over to their place in the morning.